# Как удалить картинки с jpeg quality ниже определённого порога?

Tags: cmd, bat, imagemagick

Есть папка с картинками в формате jpg. Каждая из них из них имеет своё jpeg quality. Нужно удалить из папки все изображения с jpeg quality ниже порога. ОС windows

Пришёл к выводу что помочь может ImageMagick (утилита identify). Пишу в bat следующее:

`for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do identify -format '%%Q' %%f`

В результате на экране получаю цифру качества каждого файла (например:'90'). Как правильно использовать это значение чтоб удалить ненужные файлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня устанобенная отличная `ImageMagick` версия

```
==> ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]

==> magick -version | findstr "^Ver"
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.5-4 Q16 x64 2017-03-25 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Несмотря на это, следующий *комментированный* `652880.bat` скрипт может помочь.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
:: Сохраняет текущий каталог для использования командой POPD, 
::                           а затем переходит в указанный каталог.
pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\Leskovec 2016-04-30\"
:: Оригинальный .bat скрипт
for /R %%f in (*.jpg) do magick identify -format '%%Q' "%%~ff"
echo(
:: my answer/мой ответ
::                        ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓   создает статический список файлов .jpg
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B /S *.jpg') do (
  for /F "usebackq delims='" %%p in (`magick identify -format '%%Q' "%%~ff"`) do (
    if %%p LEQ 90 ( ECHO %%p del "%%~f"
    rem             ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑     оперативная команда DEL просто отображается
                  ) else ECHO %%p,GTR,"%%~f"
    rem             ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑     факультативная ветвь ELSE
  )
)
popd
```

Вывод информаций

```
==> D:\bat\SU_ru\652880.bat
'89''89''89''89''94''89'
89 del "C:\Users\José\Pictures\Leskovec 2016-04-30\Obraz000.jpg"
89 del "C:\Users\José\Pictures\Leskovec 2016-04-30\Obraz001.jpg"
89 del "C:\Users\José\Pictures\Leskovec 2016-04-30\Obraz002.jpg"
89 del "C:\Users\José\Pictures\Leskovec 2016-04-30\Obraz003.jpg"
94,GTR,"C:\Users\José\Pictures\Leskovec 2016-04-30\Obraz003_i.jpg"
89 del "C:\Users\José\Pictures\Leskovec 2016-04-30\Obraz004.jpg"
```

Читай [Команды, справочники и средства Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc754340.aspx)